# How can I make 3 boxes next to each other in my specific case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to place 3 boxes next to each other. The box may have text inside it and an image covering at the left 50% of the each box.

You may wonder why I am asking it here where there are a lot of help elsewhere online. The reason is it's not working in my particular case. Whenever I make any div box or paragraph, all the contents underneath it breaks down (doesn't stay the same as it is previously set). If you look at my code you will find I have this line of code: `<marquee behavior="alternate">We are coming soon, please check back later.</marquee>`

That `marquee` works fine, but if I make any paragraph instead of that (or wrapping the paragraph with div boxes) the ordered lists under it just breaks down and put underneath each other. That means the box or paragraph can be made, but they will not let the other contents (under them) stay same.

[*Hope I was able to explain my problem properly, if not :My apology*]
 You can see my work live [here](http://7seasredovisning.se/) though I will paste my code here. The attachment shows  exactly where I want to put my boxes.

[image]

.HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>7Seas Redovisning</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>



<body>

<div id="big_wrapper">

<header id="top_header">
<h1><img src="img_akin/7seas.jpeg" id="logo" alt=""/><span class="header_name"><span class="seven">7</span>Seas Redovisning</span></h1>
<p>

<span class="mob_tele">Mob: 076-9516926 <br />
Tel: 040-133403</span><br />
info@7seasredovisning.se

</p>

</header>

<nav id="top_menu">


</nav>
<div id="new_div"> <!--only the main content-->
<section id="main_section">
<marquee behavior="alternate">We are coming soon, please check back later.</marquee>
<div class="img_wrap">
<img src="img_akin/image_1st_body.jpg"  width="650" height="312" alt=""/>
</div>
<ol>
<li>

<span class="style_number">1.</span> INKOMSTDEKLARATION<br /><br /><br />
<span class="style_number">2.</span> MOMSDEKLARATION<br /><br /><br />
<span class="style_number">3.</span> BOLAGSBILDNING<br /><br /><br />
<span class="style_number">4.</span> EKONOMI KONSLUT<br /><br /><br />
<span class="style_number">5.</span> LÖPANDE BÖKFÖRING
</li>


<li>

&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="style_number">6.</span> BOKSLUT & ÅRSREDOVISNING<br /><br /><br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="style_number">7.</span> SKATTEDEKLARATION<br /><br /><br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="style_number">8.</span> LÖNEADMINISTRATION<br /><br /><br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="style_number">9.</span> FAKTURERING<br /><br /><br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="style_number">10.</span> ONE MORE
</li>
</ol>

</div>

<footer id="the_footer">
<ul>
<li>
© 7 seas Redovisning <br />                                         

En del av 7seas Money Transfer KB<br />                 
F-skatt registrerat  <br />                                         
Org, Nr: 969756-4079 <br />   
SEB Företagskonto: 5502-1030132<br />
BG: 102-5006

</li>


<li>
Besökadress: <a href="https://www.google.se/maps/place/Skomakarebyn+8,+218+41+Bunkeflostrand/@55.5592313,12.9325061,3a,75y,153.78h,90t/data=!3m4!1e1!3m2!1sufqG4dOye4Igl8W2ATJPgg!2e0!4m2!3m1!1s0x4653a718b0946da5:0xd60c6ee131582f21!6m1!1e1" title="See on Google Map">Skomakarebyn 8E<br /> 
218 41 Bunkeflostrand</a><br /> 
Malmö, Sweden <br />  
Follow us on FB <!-- SMARTADDON BEGIN -->
<br />
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
var s=document.createElement('script');s.type='text/javascript';s.async = true;
s.src='http://s1.smartaddon.com/share_addon.js';
var j =document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];j.parentNode.insertBefore(s,j);
})();
</script>

<a href="http://www.smartaddon.com/?share" title="Share Button" onclick="return sa_tellafriend('www.7seasredovisning.se','bookmarks')"><img alt="Share" src="http://s1.smartaddon.com/s8.png" border="0" /></a>

                        <br />Designed & Developed by <a href="http://jabiralfatah.com/" title="Visit my Website">Jabir Al Fatah</a><br />
                        Copyright @ 2014 <a href="http://dhbangladesh.com/"title="Visit DH BANGLADESH">DH BANGLADESH in SWEDEN.</a>

</li>

<li>
Tel: 040-133403<br />
Mob: 076-9516926<br />
e-Mail: info@7seasredovisning.se<br/>
<a href="http://7seasredovisning.se/">www.7seasredovisning.se</a><br/>
<span id="webstat">
<script src="http://stats.webstat.se/assets/stat_isp2.php"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
document.write("<" + "script src=\"http://stats.webstat.se/statCounter.asp?id=38356&size=" + screen.width + "x" + screen.height + "&depth=" + screen.colorDepth + "&referer=" + escape(document.referrer) + "&isp=" + info2+ "\"></" + "script>"); 
-->
</script>
</span>
<!-- Slut WEBSTAT.SE kod -->

</li>

</ul>


</footer>

</div>

</body>


</html>
```

.CSS:

```
*{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
#top_header h1 {

font:bold 4em Fantasy;

margin-top:-20px;

color:#006400;
text-shadow:2px 2px 2px orange;

}

.header_name{
margin-left:80px;

}

.seven{
color:orange;
font-size:1.2em;
text-shadow:2px 2px 2px #006400;
}
#top_header p {

margin-top:-100px;

color:#00008B;
float:right;
font-family:Euphemia;

}

.mob_tele{
font-size:12.5px;
}

h2{

font:bold 14px Tahoma;
}
header,section,footer,aside,nav,article,hgroup{
display:block;

}
body{
width:100%;
display:-webkit-box;
display:-o-box;
display:-moz-box;
/*
display:-ms-box;
*/
 display:-ms-flexbox;
   -ms-flex-pack:center;
   -ms-flex-align:center;


box-pack:center;
-webkit-box-pack:center;
-moz-box-pack:center;
-webkit-box-pack:center;
-ms-box-pack:center;
-o-box-pack:center;
background-color:#E6E6FA;


}


#big_wrapper{
max-width:1200px;
margin:20px auto;


display:-webkit-box;
display:-o-box;
display:-moz-box;
display:-ms-box;
box-orient:vertical;
-webkit-box-orient:vertical;
-moz-box-orient:vertical;
-ms-box-orient:vertical;
box-flex:1;
-webkit-box-flex:1;
-moz-box-flex:1;
-ms-box-flex:1;
background-color:white;
-webkit-box-shadow:  0 0 2px 2px gray;

}


#top_header{

border:3px soild gray;
padding:20px;

}



#logo{
padding-top:20px;

}

#top_menu{
border-top: 5px solid #20B2AA;
border-radius:4px;
box-shadow:2px 2px 2px #424242;

color:black;
}


#new_div{
display:block;
display:-moz-box;
display:-o-box;
display:-ms-box;
box-orient:horizontal;
-webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
-moz-box-orient:horizontal;
-ms-box-orient:horizontal;


}

#main_section{
/*
border: 1px solid blue;
*/
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
-moz-box-flex: 1;
-ms-box-flex: 1;
-o-box-flex: 1;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
padding: 20px;
/

}

#main_section li{

margin-left:12px;
display:inline-block;

font-family:Euphemia;

font-weight:bold;
/*
color:#D2691E;
*/
color:green;


}
.style_number{
font: italic 1.2em Georgia, Times, serif;
font-weight:bold;
color:#4169E1;
}


#main_section marquee{
font-family:Segoe Print;
font-size:40px;
font-weight:bold;
margin-bottom:40px;
color:#B22222;
}

.img_wrap{
float:right;
position:relative;

}

.img_wrap::before{
   background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 15%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 90%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(to left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 15%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 90%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(to left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 15%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 90%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(to left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 15%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 90%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 15%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 90%);
    content:"\00a0";

    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;

}

#the_footer{
/*
text-align:center;
*/
background:#F0F8FF;
/*
padding:20px;
*/
border-top:2px solid green;

}
#the_footer li{
list-style:none;
display:inline-block;

padding:40px;
margin-left:35px;


font-family:Euphemia;
font-size:13px;
}
#the_footer a{
text-decoration: none;

}
#the_footer a:hover{
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: You need to post the code that *doesn't* work.

Comment: ..and that a terrible way of making lists. AND the `<marquee>` tag has been retired - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

Comment: Paulie_D, what is your suggestion please?

Comment: Pointy, you can look here: http://jsfiddle.net/7373wqya/   I applied Syahrul's answer, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Paulie_D , I changed that terrible way into div tag. now everything is working perfcetly. thank you you for pointing out that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example to get you started.

```css
.box {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">Box 1</div>
<div class="box">Box 2</div>
<div class="box">Box 3</div>
```

Comment: it doesn't work. same as before. again it breaks down the contents. see here: http://jsfiddle.net/7373wqya/

Comment: i solved it finally. the way i made list want appropriate. thanks to Paulie_D